# problems displaying post details in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have the following problem related to **displaying the details title and content** of the blog posts.

**I would like only the information in the post I accessed to appear.**

*Controller*

```php
public function site($posts)
{
    $theme = get_option('active_theme', 'default');

    if (file_exists(resource_path() . "/views/theme/$theme/postare/$posts.blade.php")) {
        return view("theme.$theme.template.$posts");
    } else {
        abort(404);
    }
}
```

*Blade*

```html
@foreach (\App\Posts::all() as $posts)
    <div class="col-md col-lg ml-auto mr-auto">

        <h4 class="text-primary"> Sub title </h4>

        <h2 class=""><strong> {{ get_array_data($posts->title) }} </strong></h2>

        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" viewBox="0 0 40 20" width="40" class="mb-30 svg-primary"
            src="images/gallery/decor/line-h-1.svg" alt="sep">
            <path d="m0 8h40v4h-40z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
        </svg>
        
        <p class=""> {!! get_array_data($posts->content) !!} </p>

    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Where $posts came to site method from?  Is it single post or collection of posts? Where is that site method? What is  the route? Why do you query data inside the view instead of the controller? It's not, definetally not, a proper way of structuring your app. Use controllers whenever you touch any model for any reason. But let's start with route and the controller that contains site method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you for your help. I solved it like this:
in controller:
public function show(Posts $posts, $id)//show only selected post

```
  {
    $posts = Posts::find($id);
    return view('theme.default.template.post_detalii', compact(['posts']));

        
  }
```

in blade:

```
<div class="col-md col-lg ml-auto mr-auto">
                            <h4 class="text-primary">Sub title</h4>
                            <div itemscope itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
                            <h2  itemprop="name" class=""><strong>{!!( get_array_data($posts->title) )!!}</strong></h2>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" viewBox="0 0 40 20" width="40" class="mb-30 svg-primary" src="images/gallery/decor/line-h-1.svg" alt="sep"><path d="m0 8h40v4h-40z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
                            <div itemscope itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
                            <p itemprop="text" class="">{!!( get_array_data($posts->content) )!!}</p>
                            
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First at your controller just use this code

```
public function site($posts)
    {
        $datapost = Posts::all();

        $theme = get_option('active_theme','default');
       

        if( file_exists( resource_path() . "/views/theme/$theme/postare/$posts.blade.php") ){    
            return view("theme.$theme.template.$posts");
            
        }else{
            abort(404);
        }

        return view ('yourroute', compact(['datapost', 'theme']));

        // $post = Posts::where('posts_id', $posts->id)->get();
    }
```

And add the model to the controller

```
use App\Models\Posts;
```

Then in your blade view use

```
@foreach($datapost as $posts)
<div class="col-md col-lg ml-auto mr-auto">
    <h4 class="text-primary">Sub title</h4>
    <h2 class=""><strong>{{ get_array_data($posts->title) }}</strong></h2>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" viewBox="0 0 40 20" width="40" class="mb-30 svg-primary" src="images/gallery/decor/line-h-1.svg" alt="sep">
        <path d="m0 8h40v4h-40z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
    </svg>
    <p class="">{! get_array_data($posts->content) !}</p>

</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: thank you. He gives me the next mistake[2022-02-21 15:40:26] production.ERROR: Undefined variable: datapost (View: /var/www/vhosts/webbuilders.site/httpdocs/resources/views/theme/default/template/post_detalii.blade.php)

Comment: so use Post::find($posts);